# SQL Server Agrupando Condicionalmente

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Estou com o seguinte problema.

Possuo uma relação entre 2 tabelas (1)TB_LOG_Relac_NFs e (2)TB_FAT_NotaFiscal_Item.

A tabela de 2 é onde gravo tanto notas de entrada como de saída.

Já a 1 é uma que guarda a referencia das notas de saída com as notas de entrada.

Guardo essa referencia pois trabalho com conceito de consumo de saldo, ou seja, todas minhas notas de saída devem consumir a quantidade de alguma nota de entrada.

Uma nota de saída pode consumir mais de uma nota de entrada.
Uma nota de entrada possui um código de operação e eu posso referencio-a em uma nota de saída notas de entrada com diferentes códigos de operação.

Meu problema é justamente nestes casos. Se os códigos de operação forem 2502,1501,1502,2501 eu preciso marcar um campo novo como "S", senão for esses códigos ele precisa ser "N", porém, se houver uma nota de saída com mais de um código, eu preciso marca-lo como "S" também.

Eu tentei fazer um count dentro do case porém ele não me ajudou muito.

Essa foi a query q eu consegui até agora

```
>  select
>     rl.CD_Empresa, 
>     rl.Nr_LanctoFiscal_Saida,
>     rl.ID_NFItem_Saida, 
>     ST_RE = CASE WHEN NIC.CD_CFOP IN (2502,1501,1502,2501) THEN 'S' 
>             WHEN  (select COUNT(*)
>                 from TB_LOG_Relac_NFs aarl
>                 join TB_FAT_NotaFiscal_Item aanic on aarl.Nr_LanctoFiscal_Entrada=aanic.Nr_LanctoFiscal and
> aanic.ID_NFItem=aarl.ID_NFItem_Entrada
>                 join TB_FAT_NotaFiscal_Item aanil on aarl.Nr_LanctoFiscal_Saida=aanil.Nr_LanctoFiscal and
> aanil.ID_NFItem=aarl.ID_NFItem_Saida
>                 where  aarl.Nr_LanctoFiscal_Saida=rl.Nr_LanctoFiscal_Saida and
> aarl.ID_NFItem_Saida=rl.ID_NFItem_Saida) >1 THEN 's'
>     ELSE 'N' END,
>     sum(rl.QTD_Relacinada) QTD_Relacinada from TB_LOG_Relac_NFs rl join TB_FAT_NotaFiscal_Item nic on
> rl.Nr_LanctoFiscal_Entrada=nic.Nr_LanctoFiscal and
> nic.ID_NFItem=rl.ID_NFItem_Entrada join TB_FAT_NotaFiscal_Item nil on
> rl.Nr_LanctoFiscal_Saida=nil.Nr_LanctoFiscal and
> nil.ID_NFItem=rl.ID_NFItem_Saida where   nil.Nr_LanctoFiscal=59725
> group by
>     rl.CD_Empresa, 
>     rl.Nr_LanctoFiscal_Saida,
>     rl.ID_NFItem_Saida,
>     NIC.CD_CFOP
```

E o resultado continua em duas linhas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No seu "group by" o que significa NIC.CD_CFOP? Está faltando agrupar pelo campo ST_RE

Comment: Pensou em uma function ? Outra solução poderia ser uma coluna em TB_LOG_Relac_NFs  alimentada por triggers

Comment: adiciona manualmente mesmo o resultado esperado? não saquei direito como deve ser o resultado.